# Load fasttext model faster by excluding certain vocabulary

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, stanford-nlp, fasttext

Loading the pretrained fasttext wordvectors released by Facebook Research take a very long time on a local machine, which I do like this:

```
model =  fs.load_word2vec_format('wiki.en.vec') 
print(model['test']) # get the vector of the word 'test'
```

I am seeking to reduce the load time by **removing wordvectors for words that don't appear in my dataset**. I.e. I want to reduce the pretrained vector model to the words that comprise the dataset I need to analyse, which is a subset of the pre-trained model.

I was about to try and build a new model by extracting the wordvectors I need and saving to a new model, but the type would change from *FastTextKeyedVectors* to *FastText*:

```
#model2 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(iter=1)
#model2 = FastText()
for word in words:
    if (word in model):
       model2[] = model[word]
```

How can I reduce my load time ? Do my approaches make sense or am I on the wrong path ?

Answer (score 3):

If it is possible to iterate over the .vec format, that would be the quickest way to eliminate the words that you don't want. To know this, you should look into the structure of the database. If it is something close to xml formatting, that should be doable, and how to iterate over an xml file in python is widely documented.

However, concerning your approach and supposing that you just loaded in RAM the whole `model` in the form of a dictionary, just a quick tip, use a comprehension syntax:

```
model={model[word] for word in model if word in mywords}
```

Where `mywords` is a list of the words that you want to keep.

Comment: This throws the error that "int is not iterable" , yet none of the structures involved is of type int. Can you help ?